# Distinguishing between global and national population changes of a species (a theoretical question)

Tags: time-series

So I have global and national population estimates of a migrating bird species. The species is declining nationally, but it is also declining slightly throughout the world. I want to know if the decline seen in the my country is really because of the global population decline or is it really because of other factors that have been operating in my country.

What kind of statistical analyses should I conduct to prove that the population changes seen in my country are not significantly connected to the global population changes and what's happening in my country is not totally due to the global population change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to transform your variable into a form which has the same unit, so that comparison has meaning. If you can express both as relative percentages (-5% at time 1, -10% at time 2, ...) then you can compare these directly using a linear mixed model, there you would get coefficients for the slopes which you can statistically test against each other.

Comment: They both have the same units which is number of individuals. In this linear model, what is the response variable and what is (are) the predictor variables? And thank you for taking time to answer.

Comment: @KO88 Number of individuals is the same unit, however they are not compareable, since there will be a lot more birds in the country as a whole then in just one region. You need to transform it from an absolute value to a relative value, such as proportion. In that case, number / proportion of birds is your dependent variable (DV) and you independent variable is time (IV).

Comment: I think I got it. So I will calculate the percent losses for each and then compare them to see if they are significantly connected or not. Am I right?

Comment: @KO88 Yes, the percent losses are calculated separately. Then you compare the percent losses over time between them, to see if one has a sharper decrease in percentages.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @user2974951.